# Как записать число из строки в переменную int без конвертации?

Tags: c#

К примеру у меня есть строка, в которой записаны числа. Мне нужно какое-то число из этой строки записать в переменную типа int32. При использовании ConvertTo или Parse числа конвертируются по таблице ANCII. К примеру, единица из строки превращается в 49 в переменной. Что нужно сделать что бы число не конвертировалось?

Comment: приведите пример кода...каким образом вы конвертируете? как я понимаю в строке находятся несколько чисел...получается вы в int конвертируете `char` чтоли

Comment: А я бы ещё и на пример входных данных глянул, что-то мне кажется, что там _несколько_ чисел, да ещё разделённых каким-нибудь странным сепаратором.

Comment: Автор, небось, пишет что-то типа `int.Parse(s[0])`

Comment: @RandomDude, так вы конвертируете число или *одну цифру*? Просто очень похоже что вы берете символ из строки а он имеет тип char, не string.

Answer (score 2):

Какой-то странный эффект вы описываете, всё работает:

```
var source = "123";
int result;
if(int.TryParse(source, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Успешно сконвертировано в число: {result}");
}
```

> К примеру у меня есть строка ,в которой записаны числа.

Должно быть одно число.

Если чисел несколько — предварительно разбейте строку на подстроки:

```
var abc = "123 456";
var source = abc.Split(' ');

foreach (var element in source)
{
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(element, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Успешно сконвертировано в число: {result}");
    }
}
```

Но для этого нужно понимание, какой разделитель используется. У меня в примере - пробел, но можно и например через точку с запятой.

Comment: Таким способом можно конвертировать только всю строку в целом,а мне нужно определённое число. Стоит добавить индекс и получаю ошибку.

Comment: @RandomaDude, индексатор от строки возвращает char. Вам надо сделать сначала Split(), потом уже обращаться по индексу к *массиву*